# Printout special symbols on thermal printer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, thermal-printer, escpos

I have trouble printing special symbols(€, £, ¥, ý) on an EPSON TM-T88V thermal printer over esc/pos commands. Here is part of code:

```
FPrintoutLines := TStringList.Create;
try
  FPrintoutLines.Add(#$1B'@');
  FPrintoutLines.Add(#$1B't'#16);
  FPrintoutLines.Add('€, £, ¥, ý'+#$A);
  Print
finally
  FPrintoutLines.Free;  
end;
```

On Windows XP I have correct printout with all symbols, the problem is with Windows 7 and 8.

I build a stringlist with commands, then send this line by line to the printer. This it works perfectly for all other symbols and images but not for special symbols.

Can somebody help me, how can I print this symbols from any Windows?

Here is the code that prints the lines:

```
var
  vCurrentLine : AnsiString;
begin
...
for i := 0 to FPrintoutLines.Count - 1 do begin
  vCurrentLine := AnsiString(FPrintoutLines[i]);

  if (PrintRawData(hPrn, PAnsiChar(vCurrentLine), Length(vCurrentLine)) < 0) then begin
    log('PrintRawData error', 'NativePrint');
    EndRawPrintPage(hPrn);
    EndRawPrintJob(hPrn);
    Exit;
  end;
```

end;

Comment: We are having to guess what `Print` does. We also don't know the specification of the printer commands. Have you checked what you are sending to the printer when treated as binary? I'd guess that you are just naively converting from UTF-16 to local ANSI, and the mess starts there. Do you know what binary value you are required to send for these characters?

Comment: I have added code how i send lines to printer. No i don't know and i can't check it. I understand that problen in different code pages in windows xp and 7,8. Can you please recomment how i can build more universal string? Before send lines to printer i convert it as AnsiString(FPrintoutLines[i]) because without it i have completelly wrong printout.

Comment: So. What binary values do you need to pass to the printer? Either we read the manual, or you do. Guess which we prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. Here is the function for to convert string before send it to printer. Now it works correctly on all Windows

```
function TNativePrint.WideStringToString(const AStr : UnicodeString; vCodePage : Word) : AnsiString;
var
  vLen: Integer;
begin
  vLen := Length(AStr);

  if (vLen = 0) then begin
    result := '';
    exit;
  end;

  SetAnsiString(@result, @AStr[1], vLen, vCodePage);
end;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Far better in my view to use `TEncoding.GetBytes` and with an instance of `TEncoding` to match whatever code page the printer happens to require.

Comment: The reason being is that it is all too easy to accidentally perform code page conversions when operating on AnsiString with Unicode Delphi.